# Controller Method Using Custom Parameter Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a problem when I use custom parameter name instead of `id` in my method in asp.net MVC controller.

My working method is:

```
// POST: Admin/Pages/ReorderPages
    [HttpPost]      
    public void ReorderPages(int[] id)
    {
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            //Set Initial count
            int count = 1;

            //Declare PageDTO
            PageDTO dto;

            //Set sorting for each page
            foreach (var pageId in id)
            {
                dto = db.Pages.Find(pageId);
                dto.Sorting = count;
                db.SaveChanges();
                count++;
            }
        }


    }
```

my ajax call is:

```
$("table#pages tbody").sortable({
            items: "tr:not(.home)",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            update: function () {
                var pageids = $("table#pages tbody").sortable("serialize");                    
                var url = "/Admin/Pages/ReorderPages";

                $.post(url, pageids, function (data) {

                });
            }

        });
```

Now, when I use different param instead of `id`, I get `null` value in param. I added new route also like below: But still, the problem is same.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name:"CustomRoute",
            url:"{controller}/{action}/{ids}",
            defaults:new { controller = "Pages", action = "ReorderPages" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I spent pretty much time in research but couldn't find the exact solution.

Comment: Both you routes are identical in that that they accept zero to 3 segments and your url will always match the first route. You also have a leading `/Admin` in your url suggesting your using areas. Its unclear what your trying to match here, and you have not shown the method which is not working.

Comment: Hi Stephen, My method which is not working is the same method I have posted above as working method with parameter 'ids' instead of 'id'. I mean when I use 'id' as a parameter in above method as "ReorderPages(int[] id)", it works and while I use 'ids' param as "ReorderPages(int[] ids) then it doesn't work. and ids gets null value instead of the data passed from ajax call.

Comment: What is the value of `pageids`? - does it contain `{ ids[0]: someValue, ids[1]: anotherValue, .... }`? And if your want your 2nd route to work, then the first one needs to be specific - e.g. `url: "Admin/Pages/ReorderPages/{ids}"`

Comment: the value of pageids is : "id[]=2&id[]=3". I changed url as: 
    
    "routes.MapRoute(
                name:"CustomRoute",
                url: "Admin/Pages/ReorderPages/{ids}",
                defaults:new { controller = "Pages", action = "ReorderPages" }
            );

But still same problem.

Comment: It needs to be `ids[]=2&ids[]=3` etc if you want to bind to a parameter named `ids`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
var pageids = $("table#pages tbody").sortable("serialize");
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/Pages/ReorderPages",
    data: { id: pageids }
})
.done(function(response) {
    alert("works");
});
.fail(function(response){
    alert("failed because of..");
}
```

Look into `Ajax` calls and promises. It works really nice and this way no need to play around with routing. If this still not passing through the ids then you `debug` through your code, but in that case your problem is with the `var pageids = var pageids = $("table#pages tbody").sortable("serialize");` line

If you really want to stick with your way of doing it. Use this

```
$.post(url, { newParameter : pageids }, function (data)
```

After this you can rename your parameter inside the `ActionMethod`

```
public void ReorderPages(int[] newParameter)
```

Comment: Hi SugafreeLondon, thanks for your solution. I am practicing calling controller method from ajax. So I don't wanna use URL to any specific HTML file. My first method is working well. I wanna know how to do it with my own parameter rather than default "id" parameter defined in MVC route.

Comment: Sunil the `Url` was just an example:) You can call your `ActionMethod` as well. I changed it for you so it is easier to understand. Routing it not your problem. You have to specify what you passing through. That is why I used the `data: { id : pageids }` line. I always use `Ajax`